# Alias place names for use in Voice Actions?

Tags: voice-command

Is it possible to create an alias for a place so that I can use the alias in [voice actions](http://www.google.com/mobile/voice-actions/)? Examples of the type of thing that I'd like to be able to say:

- Directions to Home
- Navigate to Jim's House

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently this functionality doesn't seem to be possible using Voice Search.

There is a free app in the market called NavigationPro which is a little funky to figure out at first.

It allows you to save locations and name them in the app.  You can then enable the feature in the preferences for the app so that whenever you run the app it automatically prompts you for a name you can speak.  Once it recognizes the name it automatically goes to Google Maps and starts navigation for the address.

Answer (score 0):

Try starring a place in Google Maps. Sometimes when you say the name of a starred place it will work. However, it can be a bit patchy at times.

Comment: I have for example starred my home, but I can't see how I name this location as "Home". Can I enter a name for a starred location? How do I do that?